# Neutral required at disconnect for NEMA 14-50? No neutral location

Tags: wiring, detached-structure

I am installing a NEMA 14-50 outlet in my detached garage with a 50A GFCI breaker in my main panel. Since the wiring is to my detached garage, I am first connecting to a disconnect. I bought a 60A non-fusable disconnect typically used for air conditioners.. what I am seeing is there are only designated locations to connect the two hot wires and the ground, but no location for a neutral. Am I missing something here? Do I need a different type of disconnect for a NEMA 14-50?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Air conditioners don't use neutral.  But then, neither do EVSE's.

Answer (score 2):

### Just cap neutral off or use a wirenut to route it thru

You are correct that a non-fused AC disconnect box doesn't provide a landing spot for a neutral, just a grounding bar.  So, you can either terminate neutral there with a wirenut and run 6/2 onward to the receptacle, or nut the incoming and outgoing neutrals together so that neutral is available for other users of the receptacle in the future (such as a RV).

Comment: So neutral would not be required to be connected from the main panel to the NEMA outlet? Would connecting the two neutrals be the best option here? I have a GFCI breaker so I don’t want to interfere with it’s operation. I notice the ground bar has several slots.. would a neutral connection connect there?

Comment: Do not land grounds and neutrals on the same bus. The panel cover should have a part number for a "Listed" neutral kit.

Comment: @deedatc -- no, neutral and ground stay separate.  Most A/C disconnects don't have a neutral kit available, so you just have to use a wirenut or MAC-block to splice the incoming and outgoing neutrals together

Comment: Thank you, understood. Last question for clarification- no current would flow through neutral unless there is current flowing through hot and load, correct?

Comment: Right, if the disconnect is pulled, neutral should be quiescent and you get to build using that assumption.  By the way,the "MAC Block Connector" is made by ILSCO. You'll never find it on Google without those extra words.